# Android Google Maps - SetOnInfoWindowClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick

esta es mi situación, tengo marcadores que muestran información desde un JSON, lo que quiero es seleccionar un marcador y que me envié a un activity con la información asociada a el, el problema es que, no se cumple este paso, revisando logcat, me di cuenta que al seleccionar un marcador, de inmediato envía los datos de todos los marcadores, incluyendo al que le hice clic, adjunto código para complementar la pregunta.`public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

```
    ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "http://www.app.transportessalgado.cl/obtenercoordenadas.php";
    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));

        location = new ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String, String>>();
        WeakHashMap<String, String> map;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tienda = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new WeakHashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id_estacionamiento", tienda.getString("id_estacionamiento"));
            map.put("usuario_rut_administrador", tienda.getString("usuario_rut_administrador"));
            map.put("nombre_estacionamiento", tienda.getString("nombre_estacionamiento"));
            map.put("latitud", tienda.getString("latitud"));
            map.put("longitud", tienda.getString("longitud"));
            map.put("cantidad_cupos", tienda.getString("cantidad_cupos"));
            Log.e("lo que recibe el mapa", String.valueOf(map));
            location.add(map);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
        idestacionamiento = String.valueOf(location.get(i).get("id_estacionamiento"));
        name = String.valueOf(location.get(i).get("nombre_estacionamiento"));
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("latitud"));
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("longitud"));
        name2 = String.valueOf(location.get(i).get("cantidad_cupos"));
        name4 = String.valueOf(location.get(i).get("usuario_rut_administrador"));
        Log.e("lo que recibe el mapa", String.valueOf(location));


        name1 = "Nombre Estacionamiento: " + name;
        name3 = "Cupos: " + name2;
        String name5 = "Horario Atencion: 09:00 a 18:00";

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(name1)
                .snippet(Arrays.toString(name3.split("[\\r\\n]+")) + name5));

        idmarcador = marker.getId();
        mHashMap.put(i, marker);


    }Log.e("lo que recibe el mapa", String.valueOf(location));

        final ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String, String>> finalLocation = location;
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    LatLng lat_long = marker.getPosition();
                    Intent iratienda = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmarReserva.class);
                    iratienda.putExtra("id_estacionamiento", idestacionamiento);
                    iratienda.putExtra("usuario_rut_administrador", name4);
                    iratienda.putExtra("nombre_estacionamiento", name);
                    iratienda.putExtra("cantidad_cupos", name2);
                    Log.e("Informacion_enviada", String.valueOf(finalLocation));
                    startActivity(iratienda);



            }
        });

    }
```

> 06-26 03:51:14.250 21745-21745/com.fernandobrito.parking E/Informacion_enviada: [{longitud=-71.822754, latitud=-36.140648, cantidad_cupos=10, nombre_estacionamiento=juanito, usuario_rut_administrador=1, id_estacionamiento=1}, {longitud=-0.324234, latitud=-0.324324, cantidad_cupos=1, nombre_estacionamiento=fernando, usuario_rut_administrador=1111, id_estacionamiento=2}, {longitud=-71.824051, latitud=-36.142857, cantidad_cupos=100, nombre_estacionamiento=princesa, usuario_rut_administrador=1111, id_estacionamiento=4}, {longitud=-71.824043, latitud=-36.143135, cantidad_cupos=21, nombre_estacionamiento=fffff, usuario_rut_administrador=1111, id_estacionamiento=5}, {longitud=-71.817596, latitud=-36.144310, cantidad_cupos=22, nombre_estacionamiento=ttttt, usuario_rut_administrador=1111, id_estacionamiento=6}]

y aquí esta el logcat, en donde al seleccionar un marcador, en vez de enviar la información del marcador que se presiono, se envían todos los que se encuentran en la base de datos.

gracias espero que hayan entendido, y puedan ayudarme :(
`

Comment: Puedes poner el código del método que se ejecuta al hacer click sobre un marcador?

Comment: si lo puse, es la ultima parte del codigo, onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker).

Comment: Puedes, al pasar a la otra clase, ver lo que tiene el intent? De primeras parece que lo haces bien

Comment: lo que me envía el intent es lo que sale en el logcat, me envía los datos de todos los marcadores, y yo necesito que me muestre solo el marcador que hice clic, en los edit text que recibo los datos, en la activity que recibe, me muestra los datos de la ultima fila agregada en la base de datos :/

Answer (score 0):

resolví mi problemática cambiando un poco la estructura del código, dejare el código publicado para que ayude a alguien que se le presenta algún problema similar.

```
 try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));

        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tienda = data.getJSONObject(i);

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(data.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("latitud"),
                            data.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("longitud")))
                    .title(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_estacionamiento")).flat(true)
                    .snippet(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_estacionamiento"))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.automovil))));

                    final String rutadministrador= data.getJSONObject(i).getString("usuario_rut_administrador");

                marker.showInfoWindow();
                idmarcador=marker.getId();
                mHashMap.put(i,marker);

                final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Location = location;

            googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                        String idmarker= marker.getId();
                       String titulo=marker.getTitle();
                       String idestacionamiento=marker.getSnippet();


                       //float rutadministrador=marker.getAlpha();
                       //String rutadmi=String.valueOf(rutadministrador);

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmarReserva.class);

                        i.putExtra("id_estacionamiento",idestacionamiento );
                        i.putExtra("usuario_rut_administrador", rutadministrador);
                        i.putExtra("nombre_estacionamiento", titulo);
                        Log.e("Informacion_enviada", valueOf(Location));
                        startActivity(i);


                        }
                        }
                );

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```